# htaccess make rewrite condition page specific

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my htaccess which works fine for the page called portfolio:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/portfolio#!%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

However I now need to keep this and also produce this same rewrite for another page called PrivateGallery.

How can I do this without the two clashing, is there any way to write the first condition line differently for example so that it was page specific and then copy this a second time changing the page names accordingly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually found what I was looking for after countless experiments. I achieved it with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=([^&]*)
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}#!%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

So both my pages containing escaped fragments will rewrite to their hashbang representative URLs without one page also redirecting to another.

This was mainly needed so that I could get Facebook to parse these URLs for a project where I needed like button/fb comments to represent separate image URLs in the document.